# pictures wont properly aligned using percent

Tags: html, css, layout, pixel, percentage

I have been trying to align some pictures using percent for the height.

HTML:

```
<div class="work">

   <div class="work_container" id="work_thumb" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">

      <div class="front">
         <a href="#"><img src="images/dummy1-01.png" border="0"></a>    
      </div>

      <div class="back">
         <a href="#"><img src="images/dummy2-01.png" border="0"></a>
      </div>

   </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.work {
width: 84%;
height: 100%;
left: 8%;
position: absolute; 
}

.work_container{
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
-webkit-perspective: 10000;
-moz-perspective: 10000;
-o-perspective: 10000;
}

#work_thumb {
width: 20%;
height: 213px;
float: left;
display: inline;
-moz-transform: perspective(10000px);
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#work_thumb img{
width: 100%;
}
```

As you can see i am using 213px for the height to make the images in left positioned nicely in left align. But if I am using percent, the images just covering one another (like a stack). Is there any way to solve this issue? Because if i am using pixels, sometimes the pictures will get distorted in different screen size.

Comment: Can you get a JSFiddle up please = ) makes it easier for us!

Comment: are the images supposed to be vertically aligned? because they are horizontally aligned in the fiddle!

Comment: sorry this is the correct link @bezzoon

http://jsfiddle.net/8rCzJ/1/

Comment: that link looks perfect as well? ;c what's the problem?

Comment: as you can see that within the second link, the first image on the second line overlaps a part of the first image in the first line when you hover on it. My question is there anyway to make the images on the second line properly aligned without disturbing the first line image? I have tried to use pixels instead of percent for the height and it worked, however as you re-size the browser, there is a white gap between the line of images. In other case, if i use pixels for both width and height, the layout cant be fluid in different screen size.

Answer (score 1):

you need to increase the height of either work_thumb id or you need to take less size of image  which you required and add margin left and margin-bottom for thumbs.
I think following code will help you #work_thumb { width: 20%;height: 50%;margin-left: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;float: left;display: inline;}

Create a div(class like outer) for first row similarly for second row so that first row contains 4 images second one also 4 images and so on..
than include the code .outer:first-child{margin-left:0} this will set margin left 0 for first image of each row rest will look fine